# pages keep refreshing after call javascript function returned from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have tried most answers about call javascript function returned from ajax response. Every answer worked but I must call alert to show the ajax response to see the result.(If not use alert in the function refreshResults, sometime the result will show but disappear immediately) It seems the page keep refreshing.

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

I already tested the browser can receive data successfully from the server. The problem is how to show the data from the browser side.

Here is the code related to receive data from the server and how the server return data.

ajax

```
 function sendAjaxQuery(url, data) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
      //eval(document.getElementById("refreshResults").innerHTML);
      refreshResults(data);
      //$("#firstname").text(data);
      // alert('success '+data);
        }
    });
}
```

This is how I send data to server.

```
sendAjaxQuery('http://localhost:3000/results.html',JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function refreshResults(data){
    $("#firstname").text(data);
    alert(data);
  }
</script>
```

The server side is nodejs. (The server side return a string. Status is 200). The http header is

```
"Content-Type": "text/plain",'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
```

This is the click handler.

```
    function sendData() {
    var form = document.getElementById('myform');
    sendAjaxQuery('http://localhost:3000/results.html',JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
}
var sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');
sendButton.onclick = sendData;
```

This is the according html

```
<form id="myform">

<input type="text" name="Search" value="">


<button id="sendButton" >Search</button>
```

Comment: Why you need this line?: `eval(document.getElementById("refreshResults").innerHTML);`

Comment: @hindmost Actually it doesn't matter. It is just one of my several tries. After comment the line, and uncomment the rest. It is still the same. I must call the alert after call the javascript to see the results. It is just shown use eval doesn't work either(other similar answers from stackoverflow).

Comment: Where `sendAjaxQuery()` is called?

Comment: @ Sorry. This is part of my code. Since I am pretty sure I got data successfully from the server. I will update the question.

Comment: Why do u need this?! <script type="text/javascript" id="refreshResults"> id in <script> tag?! when u innerHtml in script tag - it worked, and maybe it reloading! Give us example of data from ajax.success @AlexWei

Comment: try to remove id="refreshResults" from <script> tag, and show example of data from ajax success

Comment: How are you calling the `sendAjaxQuery` ? Because it has a parameter `refreshResults`. So if you pass itself in there it will keep calling itself..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Ok I will try again and update the question in a moment.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I have updated the question. It is the same result. I will upload a picture in a moment.

Comment: Are you doing this when clicking a submit button from a form ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes.

Comment: @AlexWei that is where the problem lies then.. You need to cancel the original event so the browser does not submit the form (*since you handle the submit through ajax*). Show us the click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the whole point of the `sendAjaxQuery` method ?

It just recreates what the `$.post` does

Just use

```
// url and data should be whatever you pass to sendAjaxQuery now
$.post(url, data, refreshResults);
```

whenever you want to make an ajax call..

---

**Update** Seeing that you are submitting the contents of a form, the problem might be that you allow the form to be submitted the normal way as well (*which causes a refresh of the page*).

You will need to cancel the normal action of the button that started this action..

Since you are using jQuery, it is better to use that for binding the event handlers

change

```
var sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');
sendButton.onclick = sendData;
```

to

```
$('#sendButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    sendData();
});
```

Comment: @AlexWei, most likely you need to cancel the normal form submission.

Comment: if you post the `click` handler you bind to the button i could tell you what to add..

Comment: @AlexWei just updated my answer with the code you need to change

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks so much. It take me many hours to do it.